# How can I monitor and log data connection mode and rate, and log with location?

Tags: data-connection, logging, cellular-radio, data-monitoring

I would like to understand what connection type and theoretical data rate my phone is using for its data connection, and how it changes with different locations.  I'm not looking for an actual data speed test like speedtest.net, but rather a logging of the type of data connection (GPRS, HSDPA, HSDPA+) and the specific modulation and UE Categories ([see the table for User Equipment (UE) categories in this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Speed_Downlink_Packet_Access)).

This information should be available from the phone's radio, without actually sending additional data through the network.

I would like to have this information logged, along with a rough location, maybe as a background process (which would only run when a data connection is active so it would not drain the battery).

Answer (score 2):

I think that the network data you need is available through logcat. View the network buffer on your phone using either [alogcat (Android 4.0 and earlier)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en) or [adb (any, but required for Android 4.1 and later)](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#alternativeBuffers). I had to use this statement in adb:

```
adb logcat -b radio GsmSST:D *:S
```

The resulting list included log entries like the one below:

```
D/GsmSST  (  707): [GsmSST] handlPollStateResultMessage: GsmSST setDataRegState=0 regState=1 dataRadioTechnology=9
```

This is from a Galaxy Nexus which is GSM - if your phone is CDMA it will look very different and will need a different adb command. Note the `dataRadioTechnology`portion. Do a little testing to work out what the numbers mean (my Google-foo isn't working well enough to find the answer online).

Then, all you need to do is track your location using whatever method you like. Correlate the logcat output with your location logs using timestamps and see what you get!

Answer (score 1):

Sort of a side-ways answer here: Do you have the android / eclipse development environment set up ?  I don't have a specific answer, but viewing the log files in verbose mode with no filters on will show you almost everything the phone is doing (... or at least what the programmers have chosen to note in the log files. We programmers are often lazy and forget to turn the logs off after we're done debugging. )  So at the very least, the logs may reveal which radio / connectivity services are active. And from there, you might find via google some info about any interfaces they expose. Watching the log files reveals a ton of interesting things.

Answer (score 1):

WEll If you want to see the log data on Android besis on location, there is an app for this which is named as GeoLog. You can read more about app here http://topbestfreeapps.com/save-sensors-data-of-android-device-with-geolog-app/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it logs location but I think it does most of everything else you're looking for:

[Network Log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.networklog)

I use it every now and then to monitor net traffic and it works really well.

Answer (score 1):

Try Network Speed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=netspeed.pt 
It logs all your data along with its type.Obviously it will not log your location.
I use it everytime.Its size is just 43 kb and is free.Give it a try.

Comment: I have been using Network Speed for quite a while. It only indicates data throughput. As I mentioned in the original post, I'm looking for a way to log the _type_ of connection (GPRS, HSPA, LTE, etc) and the specific modulation (theoretical data rate) that the network is supporting/providing at a given geolocation. So far I have found nothing that does this.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Stats Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sebastian.stats) app. It not only shows you data transferred via GPRS/HSDPA and WiFi (separately). It even shows you calls and message logs.

Comment: The link to the app does not work anymore

Answer (score -3):

**Settings>Data Usage** logs all network traffic, available from jelly bean

Comment: Please be more specific with your answer and provide an answer that fully takes into account what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Where does that log data speed and connection type, as the OP requested? "Amount of data being used per app" was not asked for. Moreover, there is no entry named "somewhere" (you probably refer to *Settings->Data usage?*).